# zero array size not allowed in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

```
//main.cpp
int main()
{
    int x[0];
    return 0;
}

//some class. for example stack
template<class T>
Stack::Stack(): _someParam(new T[0])
{ ... }
```

in first case VS13 says that i can not create array zero-size, but in the second case VS allow me to initialize array with size equals 0. Why does this happen?

Comment: An array and a pointer are different types (`new T[0]` doesn't evaluate in an array but rather in a pointer)

Comment: The suggested duplicate doesn't ask about the dynamic allocation of zero-size array, but the accepted answer does bring it up complete with quotes from the standard.

Comment: @ShafikYaghmour the new duplicate does not answer why `int x[0];` is not allowed. The answer to the previous duplicate answered both that, and also why zero-sized dynamic array is OK.

Comment: Why would you want to be allowed to declare an `int x[0]` ? Would it make any difference?

Comment: @tobi303, i just want to know what the differences between this methods